# how to autorun oracle LOV

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I create an `LOV` in Oracle Forms but it runs only when I press on item and `Edit->Display list`. I want this list to display when I click on the item. Should I use the `WHEN MOUSE CLICK` trigger, and what code should I use?

Comment: look to the trigger in "Display list".

Comment: But if you realy want to know:
dummy := SHOW_LOV('LOV_NAME');

Comment: @DARK_A, go ahead and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to the trigger `WHEN MOUSE CLICK` in "Display list".

Or try func.:

`dummy := SHOW_LOV('LOV_NAME');`

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the LOV properties called "Automatic Display" defaulted to "No". Set it "yes". No code is needed!!